# Make lightning:layoutItem fill the remaining screen space

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, slds, slds-grid, lightning-layouts

I have the following component markup and essentially, I'm trying to make the content in yellow to fill the remaining space on the browser. I tried to do 100% but it did not expand. See screenshot below. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Component Markup

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12" class="header-fix-content">
            .... some content on here....
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12" class="fill-remaining-screen-space">
            ..... some more content on here...
        </lightning:layoutItem>
     </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

CSS

```
.THIS .header-fix-content {
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
    background-color: white;
}

.THIS .fill-remaining-screen-space{
    height: 100%; 
    border: solid 1px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Below is my end goal... also please keep in mind, I don't want a scrollbar on the side of the window.

[image]

I tried changing the height to 100vh but it's filling "more" and I want just the remaining space (so there shouldn't be any scrollbar).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your CSS file like this:

```
.THIS { // using just .THIS means the css will be applied to the whole component container
  height: calc(
    100vh - var(--lwc-heightHeader) - var(--lwc-heightContextBar) - 100px -
      (var(--lwc-templateGutters) * 2)
  );
}

.THIS .header-fix-content {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.THIS .fill-remaining-screen-space {
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

#### Explanation

Your attempt to set height of 100% to the fill-remaining-screen-space class won't work because its height depends on height of the parent node of flexi page related elements. Since Lightning Experience uses [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) and the SLDS uses CSS variables, you can calculate height of some elements of your component using these variables' values in case your component won't have dynamic styling.

#### `Calc` Explanation

- `--lwc-heightHeader` height of the Lightning Experience header
- `--lwc-heightContextBar`height of the context bar (the one with tabs)
- `100px` height you set for the `.header-fix-content` class
- `(var(--lwc-templateGutters) * 2)` padding around each component area on the page multiplied by 2

Comment: thank you so much! How were you able to find these variables? Are they documented in the lightningdesignsystem.com website? These is what I need but I looked them before and couldn't find any documented. I was only able to see them in the Chrome's Developer Console Style when I inspect but I wasn't sure if I could use them.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure they are documented officially but I discovered them some time ago when had similar issues as you. I only can say that these variables are always accessible when the Lightning page is loaded, just open Browser developer tools, go to Styles tab and scroll down, you will see :root element with all the variables listed and which you can use to keep up with the SLDS styling of the current page.

Comment: Thanks @Anton for your help. I have a follow up question, do you happen to know the variable used to determine the height of the oneSystemMessage? In the lower environment, it usually indicates which "Sandbox" environment you are on. I had been inspecting the root and all but I could not determine which one it is. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @jojopogi, I think it doesn't have an explicit height variable, but its height consists of 2 variables of related elements. The first one is `--slds-c-alert-spacing-block-start` multiplied by 2 and `--lwc-fontSize3`